# Computing an nxn distance matrix based off a function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Good afternoon,

I begin with a table similar to the following:

```
      Attribute1   Attribute2   Attribute3
John     1              2            3
Jen      4              5            6
Jo       7              8            9
```

I have already created a function -> dist(i,j) which computes the L1 distance between any 2 people (i and j) in the table. For example, the L1 distance between John and Jen would be dist(0,1) = |4-1| + |5-2| + |6-3| = 9. It is also important to note that I refer to each person as their row index (John = 0, Jen = 1, etc.).

Moving forward I need to create distance matrix that will compute the distance over all pairs of people. It will look like the following:

```
      John  Jen  Jo
John   0     x    x
Jen    x     0    x
Jo     x     x    0
```

With x being the respective L1 distance between those 2 people.

Any idea on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you created looks like standard City Block (Manhattan) distance, meaning you can do this with an easy call to a SciPy library function:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist
dm = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df, metric='cityblock')), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
```

Results:

```
      John  Jen    Jo
John   0.0  9.0  18.0
Jen    9.0  0.0   9.0
Jo    18.0  9.0   0.0
```

See [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) and [`squareform`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) documentation for more details.

Note that if your actual function is more complex than the City Block one you have described, it is still possible to use these SciPy functions with a custom defined distance metric.

Although not necessary for this specific case, here is how you would go about applying a custom distance function if needed. First create a function which takes the two rows as inputs, and returns a single distance number:

```
def my_distance_function(row1, row2):
    return np.abs(row1 - row2).sum()
```

Then apply as follows:

```
dm = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(df, metric=my_distance_function)), index=df.index, columns=df.index)
```

This gives the same result as the 'cityblock' function in the SciPy library, but you can see how you could tweak it now to suit your needs if required.